# Mysql muliple count on same table with subqueries

Tags: mysql, count

I would like to make a special query on only one table. Here is an example of the table :

```
TABLE NAME "market"
id    |code   |parent_id
------------------------
1     |aaaa   |0
2     |bbbb   |1
3     |cccc   |1
```

I would like to make a query to list all lines with two variables using **id** and **parent_id** :

- **child count** : number of lines having **parent_id** = **id**
- **parent child** count : number of lines having the parent of the line

Here is my query, the first count is working (child count) but the second is always **1** instead of the good value **2** :

```
SELECT
     m1.*,
     m2.child_count,
     m3.parent_child_count
FROM
    market AS m1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT parent_id,COUNT(id) AS child_count FROM market GROUP BY parent_id
) AS m2
ON m1.id = m2.parent_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id,COUNT(id) AS parent_child_count FROM market GROUP BY id
) AS m3
ON m1.parent_id = m3.id
ORDER BY code ASC;
```

The result of this query is :

```
QUERY RESULT
id    |code   |parent_id   |child_count  |parent_child_count
------------------------------------------------------------
1     |aaaa   |0           |2            |NULL
2     |bbbb   |1           |NULL         |1
3     |cccc   |1           |NULL         |1
```

Values for **parent_child_count** of id **2** and **3** should be **2** (same as **child_count** of id **1**)

Any idea if this kind of query is possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter version, not sure if more more performant or not.

```
SELECT
     m.*,
     count(distinct childs.id) as child_count,
     count(distinct siblings.id) as parent_child_count
FROM
    market m
LEFT JOIN market as childs ON m.id = childs.parent_id
LEFT JOIN market as siblings ON m.parent_id = siblings.parent_id AND m.parent_id != 0
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.code ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/911a3e/3/0)):

```
SELECT
     m1.*,
     m2.count AS child_count,
     m3.count AS parent_child_count
FROM
    market AS m1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT parent_id, COUNT(id) AS count FROM market WHERE parent_id != 0 GROUP BY parent_id
) AS m2
ON m1.id = m2.parent_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT parent_id, COUNT(id) AS count FROM market WHERE parent_id != 0 GROUP BY parent_id
) AS m3
ON m1.parent_id = m3.parent_id
ORDER BY code ASC;
```

So basically you need the same count twice but you need to put it in two different places. Maybe this can be simplified because `m2` and `m3` are the same table.

Comment: This will output "1" in parent_child_count of the first row (id 1). It looks like OP wants NULL so you need to add "WHERE parent_id != 0" into the second subquery.

Comment: @rlanvin Thanks I just built a sql fiddle and saw it :D

Comment: Very nice, your query is well functionning...
I just added IFFNULL command in SELECT part to avoid NULL returns.

Many thanks to you

Comment: @Mystral You're welcome. Make sure you have an index on `parent_id` so it is not to slow and also have a look at @rlanvin answer and test which query is faster.